# Retrieving data in database using BLOB as key in JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, fingerprint

I am using a fingerprint scanner to store fingerprint templates in blob datatype in my database. I succeeded. However, I want to retrieve particular row using blob as specifier. I wanted something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM bio_tbl WHERE blob_type = ?;
```

So how can I do that?

Comment: Can you describe the process? eg Step 1. The device scans a user's fingerprint and stores it as a blob to DB. Step 2. The device reads an existing user's fingerprint and it tries to retrieve it from DB, so as to check for equality? or similarity?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try something like this:

```
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM pictures where blob_type = ?";
    PreparedStatement pstmt= connection.prepareStatement(sql);

// prepare small binary stream
    File smallFile = new File("yourFileName.jpg");
    int smallFileLength = (int) smallFile.length();
    InputStream smallStream = (InputStream) new FileInputStream(smallFile);
    pstmt.setBinaryStream(1, smallStream, smallFileLength);
    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Still this is a very complex way of storing and retrieving binary objects in db. You should think on other mechanisms of storing

Comment: sir my question is on retrieving not storing. However, I will try your answer to retrieve the information i need. Can you pls suggest ways of storing fingerprint templates in my db? Thanks